# populate objects from webservice using pickerView (from ViewController)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.3

I have successful results coming from a webservice in an `NSMutableArray` datatype, but my dilemma is how do I show the content results to my `UIPickerView` object? when I ran this, there was nothing appeared on the `UIPickerView`, but when I clicked on the button, it popped the first country from the webservice content. Any comments will be appreciated, here I have my code:

myViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Service.h"

@class myController;
@interface PromoViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate>{
}    
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *singlePicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pickerData;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed;  
@end
```

=======================

myViewController.m:

```
#import "myViewController.h"
#import "Service.h"

@implementation myViewController;
@synthesize singlePicker;
@synthesize pickerData;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    NSInteger row = [singlePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *selected = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                       @"You selected %@!", selected];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                message:@"Thank you for choosing."
                delegate:nil
                cancelButtonTitle:@"You're Welcome"
                otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    //NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Luke", @"Leia",
    //                  @"Han", @"Chewbacca", @"Artoo", @"Threepio", @"Lando", nil];
    //self.pickerData = array;
    Service* service = [[Service alloc] init];
    [service WEBServiceCountries:self action:@selector(handleAllCountries:)]; 
    //self.pickerData = countryArray;
}


-(NSMutableArray *) handleAllCountries:(id) value{
    NSMutableArray *a = value;
    NSLog(@"myViewController:  we have %d countries", [a count]);

    NSMutableArray *countryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *countryArrayid =  [[NSMutableArray alloc]  init];

    for (LBCCountry *country in a ){
        NSLog(@"myViewController:  %d - %@", country.CountryID, country.CountryName);
        [countryArray addObject:country.CountryName];     
        [countryArrayid addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",country.CountryID]];
    }
    self.pickerData = countryArray;
    NSLog(@"pickerData: %@", pickerData);
    return countryArray;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.singlePicker = nil;
    self.pickerData = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [pickerData count];
}

#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}
@end
```

==============

Comment: post the delegate methods to UIPickerView, the issue is happening there.

Answer (score 0):

In the handleAllCountries method you set your property, pickerData to countryArray for which you have no strong reference. So, when that method is finished, pickerData will be nil.  Instead of just setting self.pickerData to countryArray, you should use:

```
self.pickerData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:countryArray];
```

This will put all the object in country array into pickerData.